# Rename [appli-tools] to [applitools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The existing tag is incorrect, the company is called "[Applitools](https://www.applitools.com)", not "Appli-tools".

Can [appli-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appli-tools) be renamed to [applitools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applitools), and perhaps set up as a synonym for the new tag?